# How to load login page as first page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework. I am trying to load login page as first page but cant see its just getting an empty page.
My code looks like
app.js:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

        .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
```

and controller:

```
        .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicModal) {
            $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', function(modal) {
                    $scope.loginModal = modal;
                },
                {
                    scope: $scope,
                    animation: 'slide-in-up',
                    focusFirstInput: true
                }
            );
      //Be sure to cleanup the modal by removing it from the DOM
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $scope.loginModal.remove();
      });
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, AuthenticationService) {
        $scope.message = "";

        $scope.user = {
            username: null,
            password: null
        };

        $scope.login = function () {
            AuthenticationService.login($scope.user);
        };

        $scope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function (e, rejection) {
            console.log('handling login required');
            $scope.loginModal.show();
        });

        $scope.$on('event:auth-loginConfirmed', function () {
            $scope.username = null;
            $scope.password = null;
            $scope.loginModal.hide();
        });
```

But still cant see it.
my app looks like
 https://github.com/keithdmoore/ionic-http-auth but without the home page.
Thnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change your app.config section.

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
$stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        }).state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "login.html page url",
            controller: 'login controller'
        }));
```

don't need to write any code `appcontroller'.  Whenever you run the application  the url path is should be empty. So this line $stateProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });` helps to open the login screen.

Comment: ok, did that now I am getting the login screen. But have an error with    $scope.loginModal.hide(); TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined. what can be done ? is it correct to navigate to next screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770861/cant-redirect-correctly-after-login-is-done