# cant redirect correctly after login is done

Tags: routes, ionic-framework

I am trying to do login page like in example here:
https://github.com/keithdmoore/ionic-http-auth
I have 2 issues:

1.getting error when trying to redrect to app page

```
Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'app'
```

the code:

```
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, AuthenticationService) {
    $scope.message = "";

    $scope.user = {
        username: null,
        password: null
    };

    $scope.login = function () {
        AuthenticationService.login($scope.user);
    };

    $scope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function (e, rejection) {
        console.log('handling login required');
        $scope.loginModal.show();
    });

    $scope.$on('event:auth-loginConfirmed', function () {
        $scope.username = null;
        $scope.password = null;
      $state.go('app');
    });
```

app:

```
       .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.placeslists', {
        url: "/placeslists",
        cache: false,
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "templates/placeslists.html",
                controller: 'PlaceslistsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

2.the second issue looks like some issue with gui, I tryed to take list examples of login templates but it isnt looks like examples from ionic components.
my template

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
<div class="list"  ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username" required>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" required>
    </label>
</div>
</ion-content> 
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply navigate to the homepage or something, so:

```
.state('app.home', {
        url: "/home",
        cache: false,
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
            }
        }
    })

$scope.$on('event:auth-loginConfirmed', function () {
        $scope.username = null;
        $scope.password = null;
        $state.go('app.home');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning issue 1, I see on the github the following  `$scope.loginModal.hide();`
instead of your code :   `$state.go('app');`

Concerning issue 2, you shall look at [ionic components](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/), `<ion-nav-view> , <ion-content> , <ion-list> , <ion-item>`

Comment: for issue 1 I dont have an code on my AppCtrl because of that I need to do routes. for 2 issue I added <ion-view view-title="Search">
  <ion-content> but still have the same issue

Comment: about the gui issue you was right it really fixed the issue. but about the other one still the same

Comment: when you replace $state.go('app') by $scope.loginModal.hide() what is your result? what is the issue ?

Comment: .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicModal) {} this my controller app and its empty

Comment: $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', function(modal) {
      $scope.loginModal = modal;
    },
    {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up',
      focusFirstInput: true
    }
  );

Comment: what is this? where to insert it?

Comment: Please look at bitbucket project and appCtrl Controller. This is all declared there.